# Error with "downSample" in Caret package in R and which function is best?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, sampling, imbalanced-data

I am trying two sampling methods with unbalanced data.
I used the "upSample" function of the "Caret" package and everything went well.
However when I use the "downSample" function I have the following error:

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

The command syntax I'am using is:

```
downtrain_eli=downSample(x=trainset_eli[,-16],
                      y=trainset_eli$Comportamento)
```

"trainset_eli" has 34 columns and 70.800 rows

As I am using the Random Forest model to predict multi-class (6) response variable, I am testing these two functions (up and dowsample) to keep my data balanced. However, I saw that the "Caret" package also contains the "train" function, with more options to balance the data. But this fuction is a model type function and I just wanted the function to create a dataset with balanced data, and then use it in my Random Forest model. Would it be better for me to continue using the "up and down" functions or to use the "train" function? If so, how do I implement this in my Random Forest model?

```
str(trainset_eli)
$ date         : chr  "01/10/2019" "24/09/2019" "01/10/2019" "01/10/2019" ...
 $ air.temp     : num  18.4 32.6 34.5 26.4 32.6 ...
 $ relat.u      : num  70 30.4 22.2 50.7 30.8 ...
 $ wind.sp      : num  1.14 2.81 1.51 3.33 2.17 ...
 $ wind.dir     : num  79.1 341.6 350.1 56.2 294.9 ...
 $ solar.rad    : num  39.6 741 433.9 621.1 274.6 ...
 $ max.raj      : num  1.65 5.25 2.85 6.05 4.45 ...
 $ time         : chr  "06:40:00" "14:10:00" "14:40:00" "09:20:00" ...
 $ timedate     : POSIXct, format: "2019-10-01 06:43:48" "2019-09-24 14:10:45" "2019-10-01 14:48:50" ...
 $ sensorid     : int  67 65 66 70 70 70 69 68 69 65 ...
 $ x            : int  -56 -49 15 35 -4 27 -40 33 -29 -47 ...
 $ y            : int  -11 0 -4 24 10 34 -43 4 -4 5 ...
 $ z            : int  -27 -37 -56 -20 -16 -44 -51 -49 -53 -41 ...
 $ i.date       : chr  "01/10/2019" "24/09/2019" "01/10/2019" "01/10/2019" ...
 $ i.time       : chr  "06:43:48" "14:10:45" "14:48:50" "09:21:41" ...
 $ Comportamento: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","4","5",..: 6 3 3 5 2 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ xg           : num  -0.875 -0.7656 0.2344 0.5469 -0.0625 ...
 $ yg           : num  -0.1719 0 -0.0625 0.375 0.1562 ...
 $ zg           : num  -0.422 -0.578 -0.875 -0.312 -0.25 ...
 $ SMA          : num  1.469 1.344 1.172 1.234 0.469 ...
 $ SVM          : num  0.986 0.959 0.908 0.733 0.301 ...
 $ mov.var      : num  0.0625 0.1094 0.0469 1.0156 1 ...
 $ energy       : num  0.94701 0.84715 0.67974 0.28875 0.00825 ...
 $ entropy      : num  0.2526 0.1219 0.0354 0.8179 0.0172 ...
 $ pitch        : num  62.5 52.9 -15 -48.2 12 ...
 $ roll         : num  -158 180 -176 130 148 ...
 $ inclination  : num  -64.7 -52.9 -15.5 -64.8 -33.9 ...
 $ year         : num  2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 ...
 $ month        : num  10 9 10 10 9 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ day          : int  1 24 1 1 24 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dayofweek    : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ hour         : int  6 14 14 9 16 13 6 16 7 6 ...
 $ minute       : int  43 10 48 21 38 35 43 48 20 36 ...
 $ second       : num  48 45 50 41 45 16 36 13 43 57 ...

> dput(head(trainset_eli))
structure(list(date = c("01/10/2019", "24/09/2019", "01/10/2019", 
"01/10/2019", "24/09/2019", "01/10/2019"), air.temp = c(18.42, 
32.63, 34.54, 26.42, 32.63, 34.44), relat.u = c(70, 30.45, 22.19, 
50.69, 30.83, 25.67), wind.sp = c(1.136, 2.809, 1.512, 3.326, 
2.171, 2.04), wind.dir = c(79.1, 341.6, 350.1, 56.22, 294.9, 
16.57), solar.rad = c(39.62, 741, 433.9, 621.1, 274.6, 847), 
    max.raj = c(1.647, 5.247, 2.847, 6.047, 4.447, 4.447), time = c("06:40:00", 
    "14:10:00", "14:40:00", "09:20:00", "16:30:00", "13:30:00"
    ), timedate = structure(c(1569912228, 1569334245, 1569941330, 
    1569921701, 1569343125, 1569936916), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), sensorid = c(67L, 65L, 66L, 70L, 
    70L, 70L), x = c(-56L, -49L, 15L, 35L, -4L, 27L), y = c(-11L, 
    0L, -4L, 24L, 10L, 34L), z = c(-27L, -37L, -56L, -20L, -16L, 
    -44L), i.date = c("01/10/2019", "24/09/2019", "01/10/2019", 
    "01/10/2019", "24/09/2019", "01/10/2019"), i.time = c("06:43:48", 
    "14:10:45", "14:48:50", "09:21:41", "16:38:45", "13:35:16"
    ), Comportamento = structure(c(6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), xg = c(-0.875, 
    -0.765625, 0.234375, 0.546875, -0.0625, 0.421875), yg = c(-0.171875, 
    0, -0.0625, 0.375, 0.15625, 0.53125), zg = c(-0.421875, -0.578125, 
    -0.875, -0.3125, -0.25, -0.6875), SMA = c(1.46875, 1.34375, 
    1.171875, 1.234375, 0.46875, 1.640625), SVM = c(0.986480882354037, 
    0.959380089563047, 0.907999389110477, 0.733044006608744, 
    0.30136408628103, 0.965847466282849), mov.var = c(0.0625, 
    0.109375, 0.046875, 1.015625, 1, 0.078125), energy = c(0.947010278701782, 
    0.847154855728149, 0.679739058017731, 0.288748800754547, 
    0.00824832916259766, 0.870230257511139), entropy = c(0.252618304422212, 
    0.121902803377891, 0.0354050216019417, 0.817915633557388, 
    0.0171719387098626, 0.109209155417093), pitch = c(62.4975813343597, 
    52.9434718105904, -14.9586823290351, -48.247900416119, 11.9694631246073, 
    -25.8994130495892), roll = c(-157.833654177918, 180, -175.914383220025, 
    129.805571092265, 147.994616791916, 142.305759533311), inclination = c(-64.6810700998259, 
    -52.9434718105904, -15.4942996397858, -64.7667344528855, 
    -33.9462950277539, -44.6176169165428), year = c(2019, 2019, 
    2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), month = c(10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 10), 
    day = c(1L, 24L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 1L), dayofweek = c(3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3), hour = c(6L, 14L, 14L, 9L, 16L, 13L), minute = c(43L, 
    10L, 48L, 21L, 38L, 35L), second = c(48, 45, 50, 41, 45, 
    16)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x56139e8dcfc0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi, could you add `dput(head(trainset_eli))` instead of `str(trainset_eli)` so that we can try reproduce your issue ? Thanks

Comment: Like this? Edit on the main question

Comment: It should work, I tried with an example dataset and cannot reproduce your error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure why it doesn't work, if I use an example set with imbalanced class, my label is named `class`:

```
library(caret)
library(data.table)
dt = data.frame(v1 = runif(100), v2 = rnorm(100),class = sample(factor(1:6),100,seq(0.1,0.6,by=0.1),replace=TRUE))
dt = data.table(dt)
```

We check the output Class:

```
table(downSample(dt[,-3],dt$class)$Class)

1 2 3 4 5 6 
4 4 4 4 4 4 

table(upSample(dt[,-3],dt$class)$Class)

 1  2  3  4  5  6 
27 27 27 27 27 27
```

We can write a function to do it, but I am really not sure why caret doesn't work for you:

```
n = min(table(dt$class))
idx = unlist(tapply(1:nrow(dt),dt$class,sample,n))
dt[idx,]

           v1          v2 class
 1: 0.24056931  0.98202652     1
 2: 0.29899859  0.69350666     1
 3: 0.05496686  1.32054392     1
 4: 0.62017288  1.49824766     1
 5: 0.67481604  0.45320585     2
 6: 0.79654281  0.49854685     2
 7: 0.74180115  0.87424714     2
 8: 0.02848226 -0.74332299     2
 9: 0.05007267  1.18599816     3
10: 0.94377121 -0.45921234     3
11: 0.63222065  0.77273476     3
12: 0.89684199 -0.74368572     3
13: 0.19782915 -0.62413381     4
14: 0.89286833  0.08664853     4
15: 0.48428538 -0.90199352     4
16: 0.08179512  1.51315151     4
17: 0.89740177 -2.28249763     5
18: 0.35267634 -0.54414029     5
19: 0.68710533 -1.99195471     5
20: 0.76743271  1.17255792     5
21: 0.80106456  0.21315622     6
22: 0.53640778  0.56632657     6
23: 0.38322745  0.74336152     6
24: 0.36704649 -0.43914106     6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tested yours and another function I found and apparently solved it! I just don't really know why the "downSample" function didn't work. Thanks!